# How to restrict useer input with a yes or no question python

Tags: python

***I have am making a game in which it asks a user to answer a question. The question is a yes or no question:***

```
print("Lying on the ground next to you is a stone slab.")
pick = input("Do you pick up the slab? Yes/No ")
print(" ")
if pick=="yes":
    print("You pick up the slab and begin reading.")
elif pick=="no":
    print("You walk forwards and land facefirst onto the slab.")
elif pick=="Yes":
    print("You pick up the slab and begin reading.")
elif pick=="No":
  print("You walk forwards and fall facefirst onto the slab")
print(" ")
```

***I have this but I need to make it so that the user cant input anything other than yes or no.***

Answer (score 1):

Use a `while` loop. Break out of the loop when they type a valid response, otherwise repeat.

```
print("Lying on the ground next to you is a stone slab.")
while True:
    pick = input("Do you pick up the slab? Yes/No ").lower()
    if pick == 'yes':
        print("You pick up the slab and begin reading.")
        break
    elif pick == 'no':
        print("You walk forwards and land facefirst onto the slab.")
        break
    else:
        print("You have to choose Yes or No")
```

And you can convert the input to a single case so you don't have to repeat the tests for `yes` and `Yes`.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by this way

```
print("Lying on the ground next to you is a stone slab.")
pick = input("Do you pick up the slab? Yes/No ")
print(" ")
if pick=="yes":
    print("You pick up the slab and begin reading.")
elif pick=="no":
    print("Lying on the ground next to you is a stone slab.")
else:
  print("Answer Must Be 'Yes' or 'No'")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [try except with raise](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html) to loop until you get a yes or no.

```
while True:
    try:
        pick = input("Do you pick up the slab? Yes/No ").lower()
        print(" ")
        if pick != "yes" && pick != "no":
            raise IncorrectInput()
        else:
            #something
        break
    except IncorrectInput():
        print("please input yes or no")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `while` loop to check whether the input meets the rules, otherwise ask user to re-enter.

```
print("Lying on the ground next to you is a stone slab.")

while True:
    pick = input("Do you pick up the slab? Yes/No \n> ")
    pick = pick.lower().strip() 
    if pick == "yes" or pick ==  "y" :
        print("You pick up the slab and begin reading.")
        break
    elif pick =="no" or pick == "n": 
        print("You walk forwards and fall facefirst onto the slab.")
        break
    else:
        print("Please input Yes/No.")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prompt user until the input is valid, you can use a loop:

```
print("Lying on the ground next to you is a stone slab.")
while True:
    pick = input("Do you pick up the slab? Yes/No ").lower() # This will make the user input not case-senitive

    try:
        if pick == "yes":
            print("You pick up the slab and begin reading.")
        elif pick == "no":
            print("Lying on the ground next to you is a stone slab.")
        else:
            raise Exception("Invalid input! Answer Must Be 'Yes' or 'No'")

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    
    else:
        break
```